# How should I allow Facebook-linked accounts to post anonymously?

Tags: user-behavior, login, security, facebook, username

I'm building a WordPress-based website where users will create an account from their Facebook account.

Users will be able to post and comment but I'd like to offer the option for anonymous publishing/commenting as well for these users (like Quora).

Would it be enough to create [user metas](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) and the associated UI? Is this safe? I'm concerned that the users could be exposed somehow.

Comment: If you want to have anonymous users like Quora, you should be aware that anonymous users cause huge headaches for Quora and are among the most frequent complaints about the site.

Comment: I think it's more a programming related question than a UX question

Comment: When you create the post couldn't you just *not* populate it with user data?